# GTK3 "gtk_entry_new" does not work in "POPUP" modus

Tags: c, gtk3

i´m just working arround in GTK3 with an input field and found a problem what i do not understand. I can write in the field `gtk_entry_new` on `TOPLEVEL` modus but i can not in `POPUP` modus. Here is my shortened code (I kow this does noting but i is more easy to read):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *inputfield;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    inputfield = gtk_entry_new();

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), inputfield);

    //this two lines are make TOPLEVEL look like POPUP
    gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the line `window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);` to `window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);` I can not insert any characters into the field. Someone has a hint for me?

Comment: There is a little warning (kind of) in the documentation. (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-new) Maybe you should consider how to avoid using `POPUP` ?

Comment: that works, i changed the code. so it works without POPUP but has the same style. Sorry for this question, next time i will keep my eyes more open.